# Raspberry Pi Multiple I2C Interface Problem

Tags: i2c

I am trying to enable my i2c3 in Raspberry Pi 4 Computer Model B by adding the following to /boot/config.txt
dtoverlay=i2c3-gpio,bus=3,i2c_gpio_delay_us=1,i2c_gpio_sda=4,i2c_gpio_scl=5
However, i2cdetect -l doesn't show any i2c3.
I also tried the following
dtoverlay=i2c3,pins_4_5
But it also did not work. What is the possible reason I am not being able to add the i2c3 interface? I am using Ubuntu 20.10 desktop version as OS for my Raspberry Pi. i2c-dev is enabled. I can see i2c-1 but i2c-3 is not detected even after adding to the /boot/config.txt

Comment: Which OS? and do you have that overlay in /boot/overlays? And have you checked `sudo vcdbg log msg` for any relevant error messages? Same for `dmesg`? Did you enable i2c-dev? Please add details to your question, not as a comment?

Comment: To OP: if you tried to update your question then make sure you are logged in before modifying. Some edits were made by 'anonymous' but it looks like it was you. These edits are not visible to the average visitor